# Why does this K-Means cluster example show 'overlap' between clusters?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I was reading the `hypertools` docs and came across this pictorial that shows 10 clusters (some seem to share very similar coloring) generated from some (mushroom) data. I was wondering what in the K-Means algorithm would cause these clusters to overlap. For instance, you can see some red patches surrounded/separated by green and also blue patches in between pink:

[image]
Link to the [hypertools docs](https://hypertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/cluster.html#different-clustering-models).

Comment: Well, they overlap in the 3 dimensions being shown here, but the data has 22.

Comment: Are you able to deduce something useful from such a visualization?

Comment: It's the most dimensions you can visualize in a somewhat interpretable way, so it really comes down to *which* dimensions you choose (I believe the `hypertools.plot` method shows the first principal components by default).

Comment: Got it, thank you :)